# double redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I have a site that does an url rewrite to a page processing script hiding the url

```
#Direct to pageprocessor
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pageprocessor.php?url=$1/
```

then urls are passed to the site as such http://domain.com/this/that
page processor then tells the site what to display. hurrah!

my problem is that I need to add further rewrite to first go to page processor as it does but then add a / to the given url, as users will link to the site etc without the trailing /

it needs to do a 301 redirect to given url + / if one isn't present.

all my attempts has the redirect use the url that is passed to pageprocessor ie

http://domain.com/this/that becomes http://domain.com/this/pageprocessor.php?url=that/

hope this is clear enough is hard to explain :D
cheers in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this may help

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path/of/folder/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/of/folder/$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/of/folder/index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Options -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pageprocessor.php?url=$1

Thanks for your response, it lead me in the right direction :D